# Exclude tag from default agenda view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

In `org-mode`, `M-x org-agenda a` will display a built-in agenda view labeled "Agenda for current week or day". How can I exclude a tag from this view?

**Parenthetical clarification**

I know how to filter a tag out of this view after it is displayed, but I would like to add something to my configuration to exclude the tag by default.

I know how to exclude a tag from a custom agenda view, but I would like to exclude a tag from the built-in agenda view labeled "Agenda for current week or day".

Comment: I've been using the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074016/org-mode-filter-on-tag-in-agenda-view to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I you don't want to see `:foo:`, this should exclude it:

```
(setq org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-foo"))
```

However, the doc string says:

> This variable should not be set directly, but agenda custom commands can
>   bind it in the options section.

So, `let` bind the variable before calling `org-agenda` by defining your own wrapper function:

```
(defun yashi/org-agenda (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-foo")))
   (org-agenda arg "a")))
```

And bind it to, say, <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
(bind-key "<f1>" 'yashi/org-agenda)
```

Comment: What does "bind it in the options section" actually mean?

Answer (score 5):

As Yasushi Shoji mentioned, the correct approach is to `let`-bind `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset`.  To advise just the one pre-built agenda view, you'll want to use advice around the function `org-agenda-list`, which builds just that particular view.  Try this:

```el
(defun my/org-agenda-list-exclude-tags-advice (orig-fn &rest args)
  "Exclude selected tags from `org-agenda-list'.
Intended as :around advice for `org-agenda-list'."
  (let ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-foo")))
    (apply orig-fn args)))

(advice-add #'org-agenda-list :around #'my/org-agenda-list-exclude-tags-advice)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(apply org-fn args)` instead of `funcall`?

Comment: @grepcake: Yes, I believe you're right.  Fixing it now.