# GTD inactive projects next review dates

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a long list of inactive projects in my org agenda file.

I want to give each inactive project a date for next review, so I can spend less time on them, on average, in my weekly review.

I *don't* want the solution to this to cause:

1. Items from inactive projects to show up in the global "List of all TODO entries" view (but switching to use some custom/special view instead of that might be OK, though I don't know how to do that yet).  Currently I have no TODO items in my inactive projects.
2. Calendar items for inactive projects to appear in the "Agenda for current week or day" view (again, creating a custom/special view for that instead might be OK).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

- Tag your active and inactive projects lists say `:PROJECTS:` and `:INACTIVE:` respectively
- Mark each inactive project `SCHEDULED:` with the date when you want to next review it

Example:

```
* projects :PROJECTS:
** clean carpets
* inactive projects :INACTIVE:
** get better at org-agenda
SCHEDULED: <2018-11-03 Sat>
** take over the world
SCHEDULED: <2018-11-10 Sat>
```

Then, add a custom agenda view to list the inactive projects to review (the following makes use of [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29838/5495) about how to filter based on `SCHEDULED` dates):

```
(defun my/org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-later ()
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (scheduled-seconds
           (time-to-seconds
            (org-time-string-to-time
             (org-entry-get nil "SCHEDULED"))))
          (now (time-to-seconds (current-time))))
      (and scheduled-seconds
           (>= scheduled-seconds now)
           subtree-end))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("i" "Inactive projects review" tags "+INACTIVE+LEVEL=2"
         ((org-agenda-skip-function '(my/org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-later))))
        ))
```

Finally, prevent the inactive projects appearing as calendar items in the global agenda view (based on [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20192/5495)):

```
(defun my/org-agenda-list-exclude-tags-advice (orig-fn &rest args)
  (let ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-INACTIVE")))
    (funcall orig-fn args)))
(advice-add #'org-agenda-list :around #'my/org-agenda-list-exclude-tags-advice)
```

Note that, because I don't currently keep any TODO items in my inactive projects list, nothing above tries to exclude those from the global TODO list (it would probably be easiest to add another custom `tags-todo` view to exclude `INACTIVE` for that).